# XAMPP: Wordpress Cannot Send Emails [mail() function] Mac OS

Tags: php, wordpress, email, xampp

I have installed a theme, when I put the "Forgot the Password" and then I put the email I am getting the following error:

> **The e-mail could not be sent.
>   Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function...**

Please note: I am talking wordpress installed in localhost.

If you are able to help me sorting out this problem I will be very appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: You need to enable it within you `ini` file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost

Comment: The problem is that i am on Mac OS, not on Windows